# Why whenever I try to call map method in Python the output be map object?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

How can I solve this problem?

```
f = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 10, 20, 30]
g = map(lambda v: v*2, f)
print(g)
```

output:

```
<map object at 0x000001C73448B320>
```

Comment: from doc  : `Return an iterator that applies function to every item of iterable, yielding the results`

Comment: `print( *g )` works but you may want g to be `list(map(lambda v: v*2, f))`

Comment: yes it worked like this thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Python map function returns an iterator. So to solve your problem, just convert the map object to a list.

```
g = list(map(lambda v: v * 2, f))
```